# Can't create correct linked list in C

Tags: c

I want to build linked list that only has add_to_end and show_list functions but my list crashes when I want to Display `head` although `item` works(look at the code).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Data
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Data * next;   
}List;

void AddEnd(List * item, List * head);
void Show(List * head);

int main(void)
{
    int choice;
    List item;
    List * head;
    List * temp;
    head = NULL;
    while(printf("q - quit - Enter 1 add end, 2 show: "), scanf("%d", &choice))
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                AddEnd(&item, head);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("X = %d y= %d\n", item.x, item.y);               /*prints 1 2*/
                printf("x = %d y = %d\n", head->x, head->y);            /*crash of program...should print 1 2*/
                Show(head);
                break;
            default:
                printf("TRY AGAIN\n");
                break;           
        }
    }
    temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        free(temp);
        temp = head->next;
        head = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void AddEnd(List * item, List * head)
{
    List * node;
    node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    printf("Enter x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &node->x, &node->y);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        head = node;
        * item = * head;

    }
    else
    {
        item->next = node;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
}

void Show(List * head)
{
    List * node;
    node = head;
    while(node)
    {
        printf("x = %d y = %d\n", node->x, node->y);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing &node->x,&node->y in AddEnd function to &node.x,&node.y
also head->x to &head.x,head->y to &head.y

Comment: request for member x in something not a structure or union

Comment: but you have head=node in the function,right?,if head==null

Comment: everthing works in the function haad, node item but when I go back to main only item is altered head stays null

Comment: oh my answer was completely wrong.sorry for misleading.

Comment: node->next=NULL;
head=node;*head=*item;

Comment: m.m has the right answer.

Comment: no, first hede = node than head = item :(

Comment: what if i would press 2 at the start of the program?it will still crash. you got to check if head is NULL or not in case 2 before dereferencing

Comment: @balky head->next=NULL;head=item; would not work since item is the address of item(variable you used in main). head=node;head->next=NULL;head->x=item->x;head->y=item->y; this would work probably. Pay heed to what Koushik said

Comment: I just add that code under case 2 to see that my program crashes it doesn't go there why is head NULL and item is OK?

Comment: head is NULL because you assigned it. item is OK because it is a variable and not pointer. just declaring item as type List should give it memory

Comment: @balky please check the new answer.

Comment: what is the problem now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have written is a complete mess. I'am not sure why you need to use the variable`item` there. Find the modified code below and try executing it. In the main function you are declaring a pointer to the head of the list, setting it to `NULL` and then you are sending the`NULL` value to the `AddEnd` function as a parameter. That will not work. you need to send the `&head` to the function as a parameter so that the changes are reflected back to the calling function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Data
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Data * next;   
}List;

void AddEnd(List * item, List ** head);
void Show(List * head);

int main(void)
{
    int choice;
    List item;
    List * head;
    List * temp;
    head = NULL;
    while(printf("q - quit - Enter 1 add end, 2 show: "), scanf("%d", &choice))
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                AddEnd(&item, &head);
                break;
            case 2:
              //  printf("X = %d y= %d\n", item.x, item.y);               /*prints 1 2*/
              //  printf("x = %d y = %d\n", head->x, head->y);            /*crash of program...should print 1 2*/
                Show(head);
                break;
            default:
                printf("TRY AGAIN\n");
                break;           
        }
    }
    temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        free(temp);
        temp = head->next;
        head = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void AddEnd(List * item, List ** head)
{
    List * node,*first,*second;
    node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    printf("Enter x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &node->x, &node->y);
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        *head = node;
       // * item = **head;

    }
    else
    {
        for(first=*head;first!=NULL;first=first->next)//traverse to the end of the list
            second=first;
        node->next = NULL;
        second->next=node;
    }
}

void Show(List * head)
{
    List * node;
    node = head;
    while(node)
    {
        printf("x = %d y = %d\n", node->x, node->y);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: if *head == NULL that was it, thak you finally

Answer (score 1):

the problem is this

`AddEnd(List * item,List* head)`

here when you call AddEnd like so

`head = null;`
`addEnd(&item,head);`

the malloc'd address is copied to the local variable `head` in AddEnd and not the local variable `head` of `main()`. head in main() is unchanged.

solution:

change AddEnd as so
`AddEnd(List * item,List ** head)` and change the code also similarily in AddEnd.

call `AddEnd(&item,&head);`

Comment: yes double pointers, I know I didn't alterd calling function variable, thx

Answer (score 0):

```
void AddEnd(List * item, List * head)
{
     List * node;
     node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
     printf("Enter x and y: ");
     scanf("%d %d", &node->x, &node->y);
   if(head == NULL)
   {
      head=node;
      head->next=NULL;
     // head->x=item->x;
     // head->y=item->y; you don'tneed this as you have it in node.
   } 
  else
  {
     node->next = head->next;
     head->next = node;
    // node->x=item->x;
    // node->y=item->y;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry,head->x to not &head.x but only head.x.

Comment: no, request for member x in something not a structure or union

Comment: item is set up but had is just null althou i have *item = *head

Comment: head is set up too in function but it doesn't alter vaule in calling function